# Rotation of element in file on simulator in Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

Can't find the answer to my questions:

I've created a project in XCode (choose only landscape orientation) create design in .xib file also for landscape only. BUT!!! When i start my project on simulator I have the next problem:
Simulator have landscape position but all elements shown like in portrait =(

How to change it for landscape also?

So when i add this code to delegate this problem exist :

```
UIViewController *rootController = [[G2SwitchViewController alloc] init];
_navigationViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc]             initWithRootViewController:rootController];
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]; 
[self.window addSubview:_navigationViewController.view];
[self.navigationViewController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

Comment: If we are talking about the iPhone here ( not iPad ) then the app will ALWAYS start in portrait. Because the UI of the iOS does not rotate. So you have to manage the rotation from portrait to landscape. Don't assume you will start in landscape by default.

Comment: FYI - There is no emulator, it is a simulator. Big difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it using

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations //ios 6
{

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation //ios 5
{


    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape( interfaceOrientation)) {
        return  YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: So when i add this code to delegate this problem exist :
UIViewController *rootController = [[G2SwitchViewController alloc] init];
_navigationViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootController];
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
[self.window addSubview:_navigationViewController.view];
    
    [self.navigationViewController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
    

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;

Comment: put this code in `G2SwitchViewController.m` and you can put it in appdelegate.m also.

Comment: 2013-09-05 12:54:43.848 Nutrilon1[1429:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIApplication 0x7573af0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c97012 0x10d4e7e 0x1d1ffb1 0xb80e41 0xb025f8 0xb020e7 0xb2cb58 0x236019 0x10e8663 0x1c9245a 0x234b1c 0x2368da 0x1868b 0x189a2 0x17876 0x28cb5 0x29beb 0x1b698 0x1bf2df9 0x1bf2ad0 0x1c0cbf5 0x1c0c962 0x1c3dbb6 0x1c3cf44 0x1c3ce1b 0x1717a 0x18ffc 0x261d 0x2545)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)

Comment: This usually happens when an Interface Builder or Storyboard connection hasn't properly been made. Sometimes you'll make a connection, and then delete the code that the connection was made to. Interface Builder still has a reference to the code, which causes the key/value compliant run time error. You can also get this error if you haven't assigned the proper class to a view controller. If you've written code for a particular view controller, be sure to set the class appropriately in Interface Builder for that View Controller.

Comment: so its not help me =(

may be exist some another method for example self.navigationController .setOrientationLandscape or something like this

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation) interfaceOrientation
{
return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
￼￼￼￼￼￼￼
```

Or We can do one thing

1. Go to Target file -> Click on Summary -> Supported Device Orientations

Here we can select our expected orientations

Click Portrait to de-select it.

Check it